# Understanding this Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am continuing a project. And this is the only thing I do not understand. It is the key function for assembling a filter string to be used for sql query. This function is invoke via onclick of a button.

My problem is the value for query is taken from $_REQUEST['FILTER'].

```
<input id="HDN_FILTER" name="FILTER" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['FILTER']; ?>">
```

At first $_REQUEST['FILTER'] is empty. Then upon pressing the submit button it assembles and return the string. But I don't understand how it assembled the string. Because it seems the function get its value from this input. But it's value is empty.  So the function should received empty from this input. It's like going in circles

Example what does <kbd>"" !=</kbd>  means in javascipt anyway?

An example of the assembled string is <kbd>""DELIVER_STORE_ACCOUNT=ALL^STORES_ACCOUNT=ALL^ACTIVE=1^PART_NUMBER=ALL^NEW_PART_NUMBER=ALL""</kbd>

And I see the <kbd>join("^")</kbd> part in the function. And it seems this line assembles it. But why is it inside a switch parenthesis?

```
 function SUBMIT(e, t) {
    array_Filter = new Array;

    for (i in array_Dropdown) {
        if (varField = array_Dropdown[i], varID = "SEL_" + varField, aryTemp = new Array, -1 != document.getElementById(varID).selectedIndex)
            for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById(varID).options.length; i++)
                document.getElementById(varID).options[i].selected === !0 && (aryTemp[aryTemp.length] = document.getElementById(varID).options[i].value);
        aryTemp.length > 0 && (array_Filter[varField] = aryTemp)
    }

    "" != document.getElementById("HDN_SEARCH").value && (aryTemp.SEARCH = document.getElementById("HDN_SEARCH").value), array_Filter_Temp = new Array;
    for (i in array_Filter)
        array_Filter_Temp[array_Filter_Temp.length] = i + "=" + array_Filter[i].join("|");
    switch (varFilter = array_Filter_Temp.join("^"), document.getElementById("HDN_FILTER").value = varFilter, document.getElementById("HDN_EXCEL").value = 1 == e ? 1 : 0, !0) {
        case 1 == t:
            document.getElementById("HDN_OVERRIDE").value = 1;
            break;
        case 0 == t:
            document.getElementById("HDN_OVERRIDE").value = 0;
            break;
        case-1 == t:
    }

    varTXTBOX = document.getElementById("TXT_SEARCH").value;
    alert(varTXTBOX);

    document.getElementById("FORM1").submit()
}
```

Comment: `'' !=` it's comparing something with an empty string

Comment: "But why is it inside a switch parenthesis" --- because an author of this code has no idea how to write maintainable js.

Comment: the guys who wrote this well... speechless, anyway  he is not assigning nothing in `"" != document.getElementById("HDN_SEARCH").value && (aryTemp.SEARCH = document.getElementById("HDN_SEARCH").value)` neither creating and `if` statement and then he create again the same global scope variable of `array_Filter_Temp = new Array; ` you could remove those line and will nothing happen

Comment: so '' != is comparing to an empty string. Makes sense didn't notice. Because I usually put the empty string at the right hand side.

LOL you said so. This project is giving me a lot of headaches. Especially the variable names some variables are just named x, y, z

Comment: @ncubica Something IS happening in that code. It is basically an if check to see if there is a value and sets aryTemp.SEARCH

Comment: `for (i in array_Filter)` is not a good idea, especially with the number of browsers that may have polyfils for ES5 methods on Array. It should at least use a *hasOwnProperty* filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever wrote this code was trying to obfuscate it, making it hard for anyone else to understand what it does, perhaps because the result is sent to a SQL query, as you stated. Of course, if you want to hide anything from your users, specially SQL commands, implement it server-side.

**1) The `"" !=` part:**

```js
"" != document.getElementById("HDN_SEARCH").value                // left side
&&                                                               // logical AND
(aryTemp.SEARCH = document.getElementById("HDN_SEARCH").value),  // right side
array_Filter_Temp = new Array;                                   // another statement
```

Here he's taking advantage of the [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation), if the left side of the expression evaluates to `false`, then the right side isn't executed. The next statement after the `,` is always executed (read more about the [comma operator](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/)). So it's the same as writing:

```js
if (document.getElementById("HDN_SEARCH").value != "") {
    aryTemp.SEARCH = document.getElementById("HDN_SEARCH").value
}
array_Filter_Temp = new Array;
```

**2) The `switch` part:**

```js
switch (
    varFilter = array_Filter_Temp.join("^"), 
    document.getElementById("HDN_FILTER").value = varFilter, 
    document.getElementById("HDN_EXCEL").value = 1 == e ? 1 : 0, 
    !0
) {
```

The first two are trivial. On the third one, he is assigning `HDN_EXCEL` based on the value of `e`. Adding parenthesis makes it clearer: `document.getElementById("HDN_EXCEL").value = (1 == e) ? 1 : 0`

The `!0` is there just to make sure the rest of the switch is executed (it evaluates to `true`). If it was `0` or `false`, then `HDN_OVERRIDE` would never be assigned to a value.

So that whole set could be rewritten as:

```js
varFilter = array_Filter_Temp.join("^");
document.getElementById("HDN_FILTER").value = varFilter;
document.getElementById("HDN_EXCEL").value = (e == 1) ? 1 : 0;
switch (t) {
    case 1:
        document.getElementById("HDN_OVERRIDE").value = 1;
        break;
    case 0:
        document.getElementById("HDN_OVERRIDE").value = 0;
        break;
}
```

**3) The first `for` loop:** (you haven't asked, but here it goes anyway)

```js
for (i in array_Dropdown) {
    if (
        varField = array_Dropdown[i], 
        varID = "SEL_" + varField, 
        aryTemp = new Array, 
        -1 != document.getElementById(varID).selectedIndex
    )
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById(varID).options.length; i++)
            document.getElementById(varID).options[i].selected === !0 && (aryTemp[aryTemp.length] = document.getElementById(varID).options[i].value);
    aryTemp.length > 0 && (array_Filter[varField] = aryTemp)
}
```

Again the use of the `,` operator to execute all commands and return the value of the last one to the `if`, which is `-1 != document.getElementById(varID).selectedIndex`, so the second `for` loop will run only if the element in `varID` has a `selectedIndex`.

The `=== !0` is the same as `=== true`.

This could be rewritten as:

```js
for (key in array_Dropdown) {
    varField = array_Dropdown[key];
    varID = "SEL_" + varField;
    aryTemp = new Array;
    if (document.getElementById(varID).selectedIndex != -1) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById(varID).options.length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(varID).options[i].selected) {
                aryTemp[aryTemp.length] = document.getElementById(varID).options[i].value;
            }
        }
    }
    if (aryTemp.length > 0) {
        array_Filter[varField] = aryTemp;
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, if you can, I suggest you refactor this code, send only the collected data to the server and do all the transformation needed on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer. You really cleared a lot. Didn't know there is something called short-circuit evaluation. Nice to know. Thanks also for the extra bit in the for loop